# Harry Potter fanfic, with Snape and a Muggle who becomes pregnant

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, severus-snape, fan-fiction

I'm looking for a *Harry Potter* fanfic in which Severus Snape is out and about in the Muggle world and meets a Muggle woman. After a one-night-stand or more times together, she gets pregnant.

When she is threatened or her life is in danger, she is secluded in a secret location under the Fidelius Charm.

The story also early on involves Narcissa Malfoy noticing the Muggle woman for a reason I don't remember, though this is what probably puts her in danger, and Molly Weasley is mentioned as the person to call for help to if the Muggle woman goes into labour.

Comment: These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (Fanfic) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11922/how-to-ask-a-good-fanfic-story-id-question)

Comment: Snape somehow doesn't strike me as the one-night-stand kinda guy, but the story sure seems interesting. I hope you find it.

Answer (score 1):

In [*Second Chances* by misundersnape](https://www.fanfiction.net/s/3598613/1/Second-Chances) on Fanfiction.net, a Muggle named Phoebe is attacked on her way home and is saved by a passing Severus Snape. They have a night together and part ways. Later Phoebe finds out she's pregnant and finds her way to the Leaky Cauldron as she hasn't had contact with Severus, where he walks in the company of Narcissa. He tries to warn Phoebe off, but can't quite hide his frustration at the situation from Narcissa, compromising himself and Phoebe. The story moves from there, leading to Phoebe needing to be kept safe and Molly Weasley being a point of emergency contact, if I recall correctly because she has experience with birth.